# Unity IoC - unit test the registration of types correct

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container

I have a very simple microservice which, for the most part, I don't run but instead rely on unit tests and integration tests to confirm the implementation is correct and will work.  Recently, I made a change and the unit tests passed so it deployed to the CI environment (integration tests run later which *could* have told me what the issue was).  Within the registration of my unity components, I create a factory and pass a collection of array parameters, example below:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl1>(nameof(MyImpl1));
container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl2>(nameof(MyImpl2));
container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl3>(nameof(MyImpl3));

container.RegisterType<MyFactory>(
        new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<IMyType>(
            new ResolvedParameter<IMyType>(nameof(MyImpl1)),
            new ResolvedParameter<IMyType>(nameof(MyImpl2)),
            new ResolvedParameter<ISomeOtherType>(nameof(MyImpl3)),
        ));
```

For those eagle-eyed readers, you will have spotted the mistake on the last resolved parameter, and this is essentially what I wanted to tests - sure, I could wrap the register of the dependencies in a try-catch and log the event of a failure but I want to capture it before it gets deployed.

So, my question is simple (or not, my googling proved a massive fail), how can I check that the dependencies resolve correctly and simulate the running of the application?

Comment: So, what is it that you are having problems to test? It doesn't seem hard to test that the container registration works

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto why remove the thanks and ps! Anywho, I don't want to know necessarily that service A is mapped to interface A but I do want to know if there is an issue in general.  For example, if there is an issue with your dependencies and you run the application you get the yellow screen of death.  I want to know if that YSOD will occur in a unit test.

Comment: YSOD means that an *unhandled exception* was thrown, so it will be caught by a unit test

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - thanks for your help on that - turns out the solution is very simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out as per @camilo-terevinto's comment when you register your dependencies it will throw the exception - simplified version below using nunit test:

```
[Test]
public void AssertThatDependenciesCorrectlyMap()
{
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => 
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl1>(nameof(MyImpl1));
        container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl2>(nameof(MyImpl2));
        container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl3>(nameof(MyImpl3));

        container.RegisterType<MyFactory>(
                new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<IMyType>(
                    new ResolvedParameter<IMyType>(nameof(MyImpl1)),
                    new ResolvedParameter<IMyType>(nameof(MyImpl2)),
                    new ResolvedParameter<ISomeOtherType>(nameof(MyImpl3)),
                ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to first move the dependency registration into its own class, whatever the particular version is that's supported by that container - a Windsor Facility, Unity extensions, etc.

That means that we're not duplicating the container setup in our tests. Instead we're testing the same container setup that we'll actually use in our application.

```
public class MyUnityExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl1>(nameof(MyImpl1));
        Container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl2>(nameof(MyImpl2));
        Container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyImpl3>(nameof(MyImpl3));
    }
}
```

If there are environment-specific values that you want the application to supply you can define those in an interface or class and add that to the constructor, and then use values like connection strings from those settings as needed in your container setup.

```
public class MyUnityExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private readonly ISettings _settings;

    public MyUnityExtension(ISettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    ...etc
}
```

Now in your unit test you can add the extension to your container and test that you're able to resolve particular dependencies.

```
using (var container = new UnityContainer())
{
    var extension = new MyUnityExtension();
    container.AddExtension(extension);
    var resolved = container.Resolve<IMyType>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(resolved);
}
```

And at the same time you're able to package your dependency registration so that the hosting application can supply only a few environment-specific values instead of having to configure the container itself.

Comment: I like this and I may review this at a later date to ensure dependencies are getting resolved. I also like the use of UnityContainerExtension - didn't know this existed and created a very simple implementation of my own.  That being said, I have a lot of dependencies (even though it is a microservice) and really don't want to test each one!